# How to update commission if agent is exist in table not new row created

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have four tables that I created in MySQL, like

1. Billing (id, userName, amount, createdDate, agentId, and policeId)
2. policy (polictId, policyName, and commissionOnPolicyin)
3. agent (agentId, agentName, gender)
4. agentDetails (id, numberOfPolicySoldByAgent, totalCommissionEarn, agentName)

I am developing this project using spring-boot hibernate Data JPA.
The problem is, whenever I want to insert the value into the agentDetails table,(the value I get for the billing table and policy table) a new row is created, but I want to update totalCommissionEarn if the agent is already present, then update totalCommissionEarn, numberOfPolicySoldByAgent, into the agentDetails table, not a new row created.
If not, then a new row is created.
Please suggest what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or saveOrUpdate method from hibernate.
This will check whether the primary key is null or 0 if so it will create a new record otherwise it will update the existing record.

Comment: I am using data JPA. my ques is when I am going for billing click submit then all values insert into the billing table and then check by which agent do this billing what is the commission of pollicy ,agentid and then insert into the new table which is agentDetails tables here if agentid already present that means update only tottalcommission value if not then create.